# Выравнивание текста: текст был по центру, по вертикали и горизонтали

Tags: html, css

Как сделать в html или  css, чтобы в блоке текст был по центру, по вертикали и горизонтали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ck2xn/

```
<div>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>

div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: table;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: вот это правильное решение)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/j4Ryu/ по горизонтали, а по вертикали наверно этими средствами нет, если только margin-top